# How do TDD to render in django

Tags: django, mocking, tdd

Need to know how do TDD in python for function success_password, i'm try mocking render, but don't undestand well what testing.

if I want to test for function success_password, what options do I have?

```
 #url
    url(r'^password_change/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change',
            {'template_name': 'interface/change_password.html',
             'post_change_redirect': views.success_password},
name="password_change"),
        url(r'^success_password/$', views.success_password),


#views
def success_password(request):
    """Método encargado de mostrar el mensaje al cambiar la contraseña """
    context = {}
    context['message'] = {'data': 'Cambio exitoso de contraseña'}
    return render(request, "interface/change_password.html", context)
```

my simple test

```
def test_success_password(self):
    mock_render = mock.MagicMock()
    mock_request = mock.MagicMock()
    with mock.patch.multiple('interface.views', render=mock_render):
        from interface.views import success_password
        success_password(mock_request)
        context = mock_render.call_args[0][2]
        self.assertEqual(context['message']['data'],
                         'Cambio exitoso de contrase\xc3\xb1a')
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how do test to success_password?, maybe render or context

Comment: TDD is all very well but what is there to test in success_password? Why not put this effort into testing change_password ?

Comment: because change password works with contrib.auth.views (django library) and i always try(test) own function in this case success password.